# I have a problem with my blogger site.When in my mobile mode

Tags: html, xml, web, blogger

When I click on the point A the drop-down menu appears, but when I tap on point B(see photo) it doesn't and appears but it redirects to a blank page. the photo link is attached

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cCCO7XthdYpuLoStj-jqgFuc6Ckssubs/view

The Dropdown menu should also appear by clicking the text(JEE)

here is the XML code of my template

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WTVVltq1ucpOnIRWW_qyw84y6w9VZBeE

Comment: please follow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

> Hey there, its a normal thing to implement.
>
> According to your question, I guess that you are working on a custom
> coded theme and I assume you can code easily in header.php
>
> Her is a plugin : jQuery Accordion MenuJQuery Accordion Menu Widget
> ([JQuery Accordion Menu Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-vertical-accordion-menu/))
>
> This plugin will add a widget in Appeareance > Widgets.
>
> Step 1 : Create a dynamic sidebar and load this widget within that and
> set all settings.
>
> Step 2 : Go to header.php and create 2 div within a parent div.
>
> like,
>
> Step 3 : Load your dynamic_sidebar() in div.menu-code
>
> Step 4: Add a hanburger icon in div.icon-hamborger
>
> Step 5: show div.mobile-menu-container in mobile size ( <=768px ) only
>
> Step 6 : Hide div.menu-code on load and show div.icon-hamburger only
>
> Step 7 : code within jQuery, if you click on hamburger-icon, that will
> show div.menu-code with a sliding effect
>
> That's all.
>
> Good luck ;)

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-make-my-menu-as-a-drop-down-in-mobile-mode

Comment: i didn't understood what to do please explain step by step